Numbered tables using `gt` package in Rmarkdown with pdf output
When rendering a Rmarkdown file to pdf using the bookdown::pdf_document2 output, how can I obtain a table with a numbered caption (e.g. Table 1: caption) when rendering a table with the gt package ?
It works if I render the table using knitr, but not with gt.
I also saw the following advice in the bookdown documentation:

If you decide to use other R packages to generate tables, you have to make sure the label for the table environment appears in the beginning of the table caption in the form (\#label) (again, label must have the prefix tab:)

However, this does not work for me either.
Here is a MWE of a Rmarkdown file that reproduces the problem:
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
gt::gt(head(iris)) |>
  gt::tab_header("Iris data set using `gt`")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
gt::gt(head(iris)) |>
  gt::tab_header("(\\#tab:label) Iris data set using `gt`, with special label")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(iris), caption = "Iris data set using `kable`")
```

And here is the output that I currently have:


Please see this issue.

Thank you for the link, however, when knitting to pdf, it still doesn't produce a caption

Still not working. It works fine when knitting to html (bookdown::html_document2)  but not when knitting to pdf (bookdown::pdf_document2)
